# Chat application polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I'm working on a chat application, which polls the server at a timeout.
The timeout increases if, over time, there hasn't been any recent activity.
The function `loadNew()` performs an ajax call to the server, which responds with message data.

```
pollTimeoutTime = 500;
function poll() {
    pollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        loadNew();
        if (!new_messages_count) {
            //Increasing delay between polls as no messages are incoming to a maximum of 1 minute/60 seconds
            if (pollTimeoutTime < 60000) pollTimeoutTime = pollTimeoutTime * 1.25;
        } 
        else {
            //Reset delay between poll to default of 0.5 seconds
            pollTimeoutTime = 500;
        }
        poll();
    },pollTimeoutTime);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the timeout function does not wait for the function `loadNew()` to complete, which causes the same poll to be sent twice or more if the timeout is lower than the time it takes for the ajax call in the function to complete.
The server thus responds with the same data multiple times, which leads to duplicative display of messages in the chat.

Is there a way to make the timeout only trigger after `loadNew()` has finished fetching and displaying the data?

**EDIT:** after using @Brad M's answer, it doesn't duplicate messages anymore. I would still like to have a way to call for a poll after the user submits a message, so the new message is displayed immediately. This would interfere with the timeout set in `loadNew()`, which would cause messages to be duplicated again. Could you think of a way to get that working?

Comment: Do you understand that `setTimeout` is for running a function after a specified delay, and not for stopping a function after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Yes, but I read that the timeout only starts after the function is complete, which seems not to be the case..

Comment: No, that's not what happens. `setTimeout` simply executes the first argument after the time specified by the second argument. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your `loadNew` function, an easy fix might be to change that function to return your ajax call (`return $.ajax({...});`) and change the code you posted to this:

```
pollTimeoutTime = 500;
function poll() {
    pollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        loadNew().done(function (result) {
            if (!new_messages_count) {
                //Increasing delay between polls as no messages are incoming to a maximum of 1 minute/60 seconds
                if (pollTimeoutTime < 60000) pollTimeoutTime = pollTimeoutTime * 1.25;
            } else {
                //Reset delay between poll to default of 0.5 seconds
                pollTimeoutTime = 500;
            }
            poll();
        });
    }, pollTimeoutTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax callback functions such as `success` or `complete` to trigger a new poll.

Comment: I've thought of that too, wasn't sure how to implement that, but I'll try it immediately. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: There is no question of whether this will work or not; it is just logic. The logic of an ajax callback function is something that executes after the `readystate` of the xhr object changes.

Comment: Is there a way to call loadNew() without interfering with the set timeout? (see edited question)

Comment: You are delving into very deep concepts. There are many solutions, but the best one is to just display message the user typed instantly, then, after the next poll of the db, verify/adjust the order of messages. (i.e., there is no need to poll the db when adding a message)

Comment: Thank you, I will have the server return the insert id of the new message, so it can be left out at the next poll.